# sequence get number in sequence from place in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recreational-mathematics

There is a sequence

$$X = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1 \dots 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 \dots,3,3,3,3,3,3 \dots 4,4,4,4,4,4,4 \dots (k-1),(k-1),k}$$

So there are $(k)$ 1's, $(k-1)$ 2's and $(k-2)$ 3's and so on. 
Is there a formula that can tell me what the $x[n]$th number is and if so how did you get that formula?

I know the sequence is $k(k+1)/2$ long.

Comment: What is the context? Homework? Fun problem?...what?

Comment: fun asked by a friend

Comment: The sequence is actually $\frac 12k(k+1)$ long

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to start counting from the end.  There are $\frac 12k(k+1)=T_k,$ the $k^{th}$ [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  If you want the $n^{th}$ number, it is $T_k-n+1=p$ from the back.  If $T_m \le p \lt T_{m+1}$, the number in question is $m$  We need to invert the calculaton of the triangular number. $T_m=\frac 12m(m+1)$ gives $m=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+8T_m}),$ so the $n^{th}$ number is $k+1-\lfloor \frac 12(-1+\sqrt {1+8(T_k-n+1)}\rfloor$ Where the $k+1-$ comes because we are counting down.

Comment: sorry i just checked this and it looks wrong. if you take k to be 4 and n to be 1 then the answer is 4 and it is supposed to be 1. am i missing something here? 0.5(-1 + sqrt(1+8(10-1+1))) = 4

Comment: I forgot to reverse the count. Since we are counting from the back we have to count down, not up. I'll fix.